# RelativeLayout ignores second ImageView?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following XML layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/IVLEFT"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:background="#ff0000"
                android:padding="1dp"
                />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/IVRIGHT"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/IVLEFT"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/IVLEFT"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/IVLEFT"
                android:src="@drawable/shadow_pages"
                android:background="#00ff00"
                android:padding="1dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

I would expect my layout to have 2 ImageViews - one to the left, one to the right.
But what actually happens is:

During runtime I set IVLEFT's image to a large image (say 1024X768) - and it covers all of my layout, abandoning IVRIGHT (I cant even see it)

Any ideas?

Comment: I can not see the id `magazineImageView` in your xml file

Comment: You can fix the size of the first Imageview or you can use the LinearLayout and using weight property you can make the both imageview size fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you have given first `ImageView` width and height to `fill_parent`. So it will acquire the whole layout. Then also, your layout depends on your first image, because if you give a large image to the first `Imageview`, it will take the whole layout.

If you want to show 2 images side by side, try using `linearlayout` with `layout_weights` to two `imageViews`.

Also give your `RelativeLayout` width and height to  `fill_parent`

Answer (score 0):

It is because your `RelativeLayout` is `wrap_content` in width. it takes all the space it needs even if it is outside the screen.

Use `fill_parent` instead.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the RelativeLayout width to `fill_parent`
2. There is no ImageView with the `id = "@+id/magazineImageView"` in your xml, if you mean `"@+id/IVLEFT"`, then the 1st image itself is occupying the whole Screen width, hence you cannot see the 2nd image.
3. If you want to see the 2nd image make both the ImageView width as `wrap_content` or some hard coded value
4. More importantly when you are using any View id as a reference dont use **+** sign in the id. **+** sign is used to define an id for a view, for the first time

use:

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/magazineImageView"
```

Comment: Hard coded value is inapplicable, as I need to image to resize according to the screen's density/size.

Comment: Density is not a matter. Because you can always use "dp" instead of "px". regarding the size of the Screen, use Display metrics to get the width of the Screen.

Comment: But if you want Images to be fill_parent and side by side. Better use HorizontalScrollView

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/IVLEFT"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:background="#ff0000"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/IVRIGHT"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/IVLEFT"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/IVLEFT"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/IVLEFT"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:background="#00ff00"
                android:padding="1dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```